# Exception on animationController is null :The getter 'isAnimating' was called on null?

Tags: flutter

I build an app with two screen. The first one is an animation and the second screen is to setup some properties.

**First screen with animation :**

```
class _RotatingCirclePageState extends State<RotatingCirclePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(
        seconds: widget.inspi,
      ),
      vsync: this,
    );
    animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: animationController,
      curve: Curves.linear,
    );
  }

...

void go(){
        if(animationController.isAnimating){ // ---> Throw Exception 
             animationController.stop();
         }
...
}

...
}
```

It works like a charm. Start the app, tap on the screen, and the animation start...
Go to the second screen (using Navigator), set up properties. Go back to the first screen (using Navigator) and the animationController is null.

```
EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE 
I/flutter ( 5888): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 5888): The getter 'isAnimating' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 5888): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 5888): Tried calling: isAnimating
```

**Button to go to screen1 to screen2**

```
RaisedButton(
          child: Text('...'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute<Null>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return new SliderExample();
            }));
            }),
```

**Button to go to screen2 to screen1**

```
RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Go Back'),
               onPressed: () {
                               _save();
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code you provide, and I have no error at all.

Add more relevant code, for example the use of the **animation**.

And how and where are you calling `go()` function ?

By the way, are you disposing the **animationController** ?

In your first page you must have this

```
@override 
void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();   
}
```

Comment: yes, I dispose the animationController. The go() function is only called on the onTap() method of the GestureDetector container.